# PyParsing: Is it possible to globally suppress all Literals?

Tags: literals, pyparsing

I have a simple data set to parse with lines like the following:

```
R1 (a/30) to R2 (b/30), metric 30
```

The only data that I need from the above is as follows:

```
R1, a, 30, R2, 192.168.0.2, 30, 30
```

I can parse all of this easily with pyparsing, but I either end up with a bunch of literals in my output, or I have to specifically say `Literal(thing).suppress()` in my parsing grammar, which gets tiresome.

Ideally, I'd like to write a grammar for the above like:

```
Word(alphanums) + '(' + Word(alphanums) + '/' + Word(nums) + ... etc.
```

and have the literal tokens get ignored.  Can I say anything like `.suppressAllLiterals()`?

Notes:

- new to PyParsing
- I've read the docs and 5 or 6 examples
- searched google

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method on `ParserElement` - call it immediately after importing pyparsing:

```
from pyparsing import ...whatever...
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)
```

Now all the string literals in your parser will be wrapped in `Suppress` objects, and left out of the results, rather than the default `Literal`.

(I will probably make this the default in v3.0, someday, when I can break backward compatibility.)

Comment: Hello @Paul, thanks for the response!  I tried this out - it seems that it works for strings that are used inline (eg, `pp.Word(...) + ' somestring ' + pp.Word(...)`, and not for things that have already been tokenized as a pp.Literal (eg, if I replaced `' somestring '` with `myLiteral`).

This small change helped a lot with the grammar clarity.  Thanks again for taking the time, much appreciated.

Comment: Of course, you can always wrap do `Suppress(myLiteral)` or just `myLiteral.suppress()` too.

Comment: You can also create a suppressed literal using `Suppress("blah")`, and the Suppress class will create the Literal for you.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the original answer was the most helpful as my grammar included a bunch of literals that I wanted suppressed.  Thanks for the other options.