# Write a python regular expression for matching dot and array indices

Tags: python, regex

I need to match the proper variable access strings ex.

```
employeeobj.empid
employeeobj.grades[0].grade
employee[0]
employee.dept.location.room[0]
```

Few examples -

```
employeeobj.[] Invalid
.employeeobj Invalid
[]employeeobj Invalid
employeeobj.dept. Invalid

employeeobj.dept valid
employeeobj.dept[9] valid
employeeobj[1].dept valid
```

I need the regex to be in python

More specifically, I need to match all the strings which

- does not start with a dot, opening or closing square bracket
- does not end with a dot, and opening square bracket
- has no dots side by side
- has proper square brackets with proper integer index
- a square bracket always followed by a dot, only exception if it is at the end, then there is no need for a dot

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example and expected output ...

Comment: how are you trying to match `employee.p{}`?

Comment: what about: `employee.dept.location.room[0][1]`? would that be valid, too?

Comment: Right now I am looking for only single dimension array. so it won't be valid.

Comment: and what about `employee.p{}`?

Comment: employee.p{} is also valid as it doesn't break any of my rules.

Comment: You are trying to parse rather complex grammar with regex. I tryed it many times and this rarely was successfull. Take a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Not an answer

This is how this might be done with `pyparsing`

```
from pyparsing import *
#see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428652/pyparsing-is-it-possible-to-globally-suppress-all-literals
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)
#the grammar
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums)
elem = Group(ident + Optional('[' + Regex('\d+') + ']'))
expr = elem + ZeroOrMore('.' + elem)

tests = ['employeeobj.[]',
         '.employeeobj',
         '[]employeeobj',
         'employeeobj.dept.',
         'employeeobj.dept',
         'employeeobj.dept[9]',
         'employeeobj[1].dept[2].head']

for s in tests:
    print s
    try:
        print expr.parseString(s, True).asList()
    except ParseException:
        print 'no match'
    print
```

Outputs

```
employeeobj.[]
no match

.employeeobj
no match

[]employeeobj
no match

employeeobj.dept.
no match

employeeobj.dept
[['employeeobj'], ['dept']]

employeeobj.dept[9]
[['employeeobj'], ['dept', '9']]

employeeobj[1].dept
[['employeeobj', '1'], ['dept', '2'], ['head']]
```

Pyparsing however is very slow compared to `re` and may not fit well for your task.